# Upper bound of $\text{rank}(A)$ for $A_{ij}=x_i^Tx_j$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $x_1,\ldots,x_p\in \mathbb{R}^q$ and define the $i,j$'th entry in a matrix as $A_{ij}=x_i^Tx_j$. What is an upper bound of the $\text{rank}(A)$ in terms of $p$ and $q$?

I've tried looking at some small values of $p$ and $q$, but it doesn't seem to get me anywhere.

Comment: Thoughts? Work? Context? https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place all vectors in a matrix as $$X = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 & \ldots & x_p\end{bmatrix}$$
Then you can easily show that 
$$A = X^TX $$
then by the rank inequality formula, we have that $$\text{rank} (A) = \text{rank} (X^TX ) \leq \min(\text{rank} (X^T), \text{rank} (X) )$$
But $\text{rank} (X^T) = \text{rank} (X) $ so
$$\text{rank} (A) \leq \text{rank} (X)$$
We also know that for linearly independent vectors $x_1, \ldots x_p$ (extreme case), we have that $\text{rank} (X) = \min(p,q)$ so
$$\text{rank} (A) \leq \min(p,q)$$

Comment: In fact $\ker(X^T X) = \ker(X)$, so $\text{rank}(X^T X) = \text{rank}(X)$, which is the cardinality of the largest linearly independent subset of $x_1, \ldots, x_p$.

Comment: @Robert Israel, correct!!